# How to create a bootstrapper with a log window

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Currently I'm using the standard `WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense` bootstrapper theme.

This theme doesn't show much information during installation. I was wondering if there is a theme that shows the log output of each installer it executes. Maybe after clicking an *advanced* button. I've seen this in a few installers but of course I do not know for sure if these were made with Wix.

I've tried inspecting the existing themes with ThmViewer.exe but unfortunately this program either crashes, or displays no preview window.

I've found a reference to something called the `ExecuteProgressActionDataText` [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/wixstdba_customize.html)

```
<Text Name="ExecuteProgressActionDataText" X="11" Y="163" Width="-11" Height="17" FontId="3" DisablePrefix="yes" />
```

But unfortunately I cannot get my bootstrapper to launch if I use the supplied theme file. I think I need a complete theme file, but I'm not sure where to find the original one for the WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLince theme.

Any thoughts on how to create a bootstrapper with a log window?

Update:

I've found the original xml of the HyperLink theme [here](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/BalExtension/wixstdba/Resources/HyperlinkTheme.xml). Using that I've added the `ExecuteProgressActionDataText` element to my UI. Its a single label that displays a lot of events. But unfortunately its not a listbox or something like that which makes it quite useless. (There are way too many messages per second to make sense of them in a single label).

The theme file seems to be driven by [WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.cpp](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/c9be685d1ab8c4053a175db0b826a47b499b259d/src/ext/BalExtension/wixstdba/WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.cpp) and unfortunately I do not see any other variables defined there that have a name that indicates that they do what I want :(.

Comment: I think you have to modify the bootstrapperapplication.cpp to implement the listview yourself. You can add the view in the wix theme I believe but you would have to alter OnExecuteMsiMessage so that instead of using ThemeSetTextControl(....) you have to add a new list item to the listview. You should be able to do anything you want in the bootstrapper application with regards to the UI just need to figure out how.

Comment: @BrianSutherland that seems about right. Could you change your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the bootstrapperapplication.cpp to implement the listview yourself. You can add the view in the wix theme I believe but you would have to alter OnExecuteMsiMessage so that instead of using ThemeSetTextControl(....) you have to add a new list item to the listview. You should be able to do anything you want in the bootstrapper application with regards to the UI just need to figure out how